# Rocket thrust over time

Tags: forces, orbital-motion, rocket-science

I have calculated the thrust of a rocket, and it's burn time for an orbital manoeuvre. I need to know how much force is applied on the rocket every half-second. How would I go about doing this?

Basically my question boils down to is the thrust in newtons the force per second? Or throughout the entire burn?

Comment: There is so much wrong with this I don't know where to start. Force per second doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: Yeah I tried typing an answer but.... nope. Variable mass systems - too much typing for such a vague question

Comment: "is the thrust in newtons the force per second?" No, the thrust (in Newtons) is the force. To get the change in *impulse* over a half second, you can multiply the thrust by 0.5 seconds, if this is sufficiently short for your numerical preferences.

Comment: @AlecTeal Teal Thanks for the effort, perhaps I did not explain my question correctly. I understand the rocket equation and have it implemented. I wasnt thinking clearly but I have my answer now! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At any given moment the thrust is equal to the force experienced by the rocket at that moment. That's the definition of thrust.

To get the equation of motion right, you need to consider the instantaneous force (variable) and mass (also variable). The acceleration is then given by

$$a(t)=\frac{F(t)}{m(t)}$$